# Мытарь и мытарства

Tags: этимология

Мытарь - как известно, сборщик пошлины (до сих пор по-украински "таможня" - "митниця"). Но почему-то слово "мытарства" стало синонимом злоключений? Это как-то связано с посмертными мытарствами?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Название подмосковного города города Мытищи произошло от слова "мыто" (торговая пошлина) Здесь находилась застава и "мытная изба", где мытарь брал пошлину с приезжавших в Москву торговых людей. Мытная изба стояла на перевозе через реку Яузу, и часто мытарь не сразу пропускал купцов, т. е. "мытарил".

Таким образом, мытницами, мытнями назывались на Руси таможни, дворы для сбора пошлины.  Мытниками же называли сборщиков мыта. При переводе Библии на славянский язык иудейских сборщиков податей назвали мытарями. Мытари были ненавидимы и презираемы соотечественниками за мздоимство.  Не отличались добропорядочностью и российские мытники, поэтому в обиходе МЫТАРСТВОВАТЬ означало плутовать, промышлять неправыми поборами, жить за чужой счет. Но постепенно слово «мытарство» стало приобретать совершенно другое значение.

Связано это с православным учением о состоянии душ усопших при переходе в мир иной. На пути к престолу Божьему  душа проходит испытания . Весь путь души разделен на несколько отделений или судилищ, на которых приходящая душа обличается бесами в содеянных грехах. Каждое судилище (МЫТАРСТВО) соответствует определённой группе грехов и злые духи (мытари) пропускают душу лишь при возмещении нераскаянных грехов добрыми делами, совершёнными ею при земной жизни.

Современное значение слова «мытарство» — страдания, скитания, связанные с лишениями и бедами, житейская мука, жизнь в суете.

http://www.orthedu.ru/site_news/937-10.html